# Locale vuelve a default

Tags: android, localización

Estoy intentando cambiar el locale de una app para que sea a elección del usuario mediante el siguiente código

```
public static void updateLanguage(Context ctx) {
    SharedPreferencesManager sharedPreferencesManager = new SharedPreferencesManager(ctx);
    String lang = sharedPreferencesManager.readPreference(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCES_LOCALE, "");
    if (StringUtils.isEmptyOrNull(lang)) {
        lang = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
    }
    setLanguage(ctx, lang);
}


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public Locale getSystemLocaleLegacy(Configuration config) {
    return config.locale;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public Locale getSystemLocale(Configuration config) {
    return config.getLocales().get(0);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void setSystemLocaleLegacy(Configuration config, Locale locale) {
    config.locale = locale;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public static void setSystemLocale(Configuration config, Locale locale) {
    config.setLocale(locale);
}

public static void setLanguage(Context context, String languageCode) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageCode);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        setSystemLocale(config, locale);
    } else {
        setSystemLocaleLegacy(config, locale);
    }
    context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

Donde ejecuto el método **updateLanguage(this)** en la clase Application.

Tengo varios dispositivos en los cuales en algunos funciona perfectamente pero en otros se setea el **Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()** al cabo de pocas ejecuciones, aunque el sharedPreferences siga definiendo otro.

Por ejemplo, tengo el dispositivo en Castellano y seteo que quiero la app en Inglés (en el menú de configuración donde guardo el valor en sharePreferences).
Nada más acabado de setearlo, funciona correctamente, la aplicación se muestra en inglés. Pero al cabo de unas ejecuciones, la aplicación se setea en Castellano aunque el valor de sharedPreferences siga estando en inglés.

Alguien podría decirme si hago algo mal o el porque en algunos dispositivos funciona correctamente y en otros no? (También ocurre que en varios dispositivos del mismo modelo reacciona diferente)

Comment: Prueba en setear el idioma al inicio de la aplicación en MyAplication.java

Comment: Es lo primero que hago en el onCreate de la clase Application

Comment: Aquí explican otra manera http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40221711/android-context-getresources-updateconfiguration-deprecated

Answer (score 2):

Puede que el error este que no detectas al cambio de configuración, donde debes especificar de nuevo el idioma.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

    Log.i(TAG, "onConfigurationChanged: " + newConfig.toString());

    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setLanguage(...,...);

}
```

Yo me encontrado con los problemas que a veces funciona y otras no, cuando hay el `InstantRun` activado. si decides desactivarlo, recuerda en desinstalar la app y volverla a instalar.

Answer (score 2):

Si guardas en `SharedPreferences` la configuración tienes que asegurar esta se mantenga, esto dentro de `onConfigurationChanged()`:

Defines una variable global para el Locale:

```
 private Locale locale = null;
```

obtienes el valor que previamente guardaste por medio de tus metodos:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
      locale = getSystemLocale(config);
    } else {
      locale = setSystemLocaleLegacy(config);
    }
```

Implemente el método `onConfigurationChanged()` para asegurar conservar el `Locale`:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (locale != null)
    {
        newConfig.locale = locale;
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(newConfig, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo utilizo el siguiente código para cambiar el idioma en la aplicación, es muy similar al de la siguiente [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2900144/3683321) a una pregunta de StackOverflow en inglés y al que tienes tu en tu código.

```
public static void setLanguage (Activity activity, String idioma){
        try {
            Resources res = activity.getApplicationContext().getResources();
            DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
            Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
            Locale locale = new Locale(idioma.toLowerCase());
            conf.locale = locale;
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Además de esto tienes que cambiar el idioma en cada `Activity`, como dice en el enlace anterior.

> And you have to set it every time you enter activity ( each activity )
>   from my experience.

Yo en cada activity obtengo el idioma que tenga guardado o que haya seleccionado el usuario y a continuación llamo a la función anterior.

```
mPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Constants.nombrePreferencias, MODE_PRIVATE);
String idiomaGuardado = mPreferences.getString(Constants.pref_idioma, "es");

Utiles.setLanguage(this, idiomaGuardado);
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: @Xose conseguiste solucionarlo? Si es así marca alguna respuesta como correcta, de otra forma indícanos que problemas estás teniendo